# Not getting proper result when using group by with join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables named users, restaurants, reviews. Here id (primary key) of users is act as foreign key uid in restaurants and in reviews table rate_to is associate with uid of restaurants and rate_by is associate with id of users table. I want all restaurants belongs to that users from restaurants table but sorted by their avg_rate from reviews table. I have used this query for this.

```
 SELECT `Restaurant`.`id`, `Review`.`avg_rating`, `Review`.`rate_to`
 FROM `users` AS `User`
 LEFT JOIN `reviews` AS `Review` ON (`User`.`id` = `Review`.`rate_to`)
 LEFT JOIN `restaurants` AS `Restaurant` ON (`User`.`id` = `Restaurant`.`uid`) 
 WHERE  `User`.`type` = '0'  AND  `User`.`isdeleted` = '0'
 GROUP BY `Review`.`rate_to` ORDER BY `Review`.`avg_rating` DESC
```

But when I am using this it gives me only those restaurants which have entry in reviews table, but I want all distinct restaurants from restaurants table with sorted by avg_rate in reviews tables.

Please help.

Comment: your reference keys are confusing. review(rate_to) references restaurant(uid) references to users(id). can you provide your complete table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see here is no use of user table for your result.You can try this:

```
SELECT `Resturant`.`id` , MAX( `Review`.`avg_rating` ) AS max_avg, `Review`.`rate_to` FROM `resturants` AS `Resturant` LEFT JOIN reviews AS Review ON ( `Resturant`.`uid` = `Review`.`rate_to` ) WHERE 1 GROUP BY `Resturant`.`id` ORDER BY `Review`.`avg_rating` DESC
```

Comment: `rate_to` is still neither in GROUP BY nor under an aggregate function. Depending on actual data this may or may not be a problem, but I'd do one or the other and not leave it "hanging", just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You have (non-aggregated) fields in you SELECT list that are not mentioned in your GROUP BY.

Most DBMSes forbid that and for a good reason. MySQL does not, and as a consequence you'll get what are [essentially random results](http://renormalize.org/post/24114561260/mysql-curious-features-non-deterministic-group-by).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the left join works two times in this case. Maybe you should use subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try listing those in the opposite order, e.g.

```
 SELECT `Restaurant`.`id`, `Review`.`avg_rating`, `Review`.`rate_to`
 FROM `restaurants` AS `Restaurant` 
 LEFT JOIN `reviews` AS `Review` ON (`Review`.`rate_to` = `Restaurant`.`uid`) 
 LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = `Review`.`rate_by`)
 WHERE  `User`.`type` = '0'  AND  `User`.`isdeleted` = '0'
 GROUP BY `Restaurant`.`id` ORDER BY `Review`.`avg_rating` DESC
```

That'll make sure you get all the restaurants. Still, it won't work, either, as `Review.avg_rating` and  `Review.rate_to` are not aggregate functions — and if you need an aggregate, I cannot see how `User` gets into play here.

Try

```
 SELECT `Restaurant`.`id`, AVG(`Review`.`avg_rating`)
 FROM `restaurants` AS `Restaurant` 
 LEFT JOIN `reviews` AS `Review` ON (`Review`.`rate_to` = `Restaurant`.`uid`) 
 GROUP BY `Restaurant`.`id` 
 ORDER BY AVG(`Review`.`avg_rating`) DESC
```

That should be better, but you'll include all the deleted users.

In order to get rid of the reviews left by the deleted users, you'll probably need a subquery:

```
 SELECT `Restaurant`.`id`, AVG(`Review`.`avg_rating`)
 FROM `restaurants` AS `Restaurant` 
 LEFT JOIN (select r.* from `reviews` r
     JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = `Review`.`rate_by`)
     WHERE  `User`.`type` = '0'  AND  `User`.`isdeleted` = '0'
 ) AS `Review` ON (`Review`.`rate_to` = `Restaurant`.`uid`) 
 GROUP BY `Restaurant`.`id` 
 ORDER BY AVG(`Review`.`avg_rating`) DESC
```

Since you have not provided us with DDL, I have not tested any of those.